# How to generate oracle Sql Statement hash in php

Tags: php, oracle11g

In a project I need to generate a oracle Sql Statement hash in php and add it into the query.

For example:

```
Select something from a table
```

The whole string can be hashed to some value, say "somehash"
Then we can put the value back to the sql.
So php will instead send this to oracle:

```
Select /somehaah/ something from a table
```

the sql_id is 13 chars and php md5 generate 32 chars hash value and also
they both should be same.

Can you please help me generating the sql statement hash in php

Thanks

Comment: http://www.slaviks-blog.com/2010/03/30/oracle-sql_id-and-hash-value/

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: we have a db intensive application and queries are reported slow, so oracle developer had to find the slow running queries and improve if possible but they have find through  log etc, we want to calculate the query hash before and append it into the query so oracle dev can search   easily and provide work around faster